# finding the mean and sd for each unique animal breed using R

Tags: r, rows, mean

Just a quick refresh. I have a data set here which I need to find the mean, sd, etc of unique breeds. I knew that I have done something like this before but just could not get the script together.

My data set:

```
aid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
breed <- c("hol","hol","bra","bra","ang","ang")
weight <- c(400,250,450,500,445,345)
data <-data.frame(aid,breed,weight)
```

I would like to find the mean, sd for the different breeds (holstein, brahman and angus)

I would appreciate your help.

Poasa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the mean weight for the different breeds with the aggregate method:

`mean_weight <-aggregate(data$weight, by = list(data$breed), mean)`

Comment: thanks so much for that. like i said, i did something like this a few days ago so just got back to that question and retrieved this:ddply(data,.(breed),summarize,avwt=mean(weight)). It's good to have an alternative script...another script deposited to my R Script Bank (RSB). Thanks once again!